# The Vue Component is not fully rendered

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use one of the Material Design Lite templates inside my Vue.js application.

What happens is, when I am routed(using `this.$router.push('/templateX'`) to the next page, the component is not fully rendered(I can see only the header).

What is really interesting, when I take a look at the source section inside the browser console, I can see that the template is loaded but not fully rendered.

**Once I reload the page, then the whole template is rendered and everything is shown as expected.**

I think the problem is in the component life cycle but I am not sure what shall I do exactly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any errors or warnings?

Comment: Are you in hash mode or history mode in Vue router? please check this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: @FK82 apart from the eslint warnings from different components, no errors no warning are coming from that component, also when the page is rendered I don't get any errors/warnings

Comment: @MahdiAryayi I am using the history mode in the vue router